# Limit number of items / length of json for logging

Tags: python, json, logging

I am working on an API that returns JSON. I am logging my responses, and sometimes the JSON is just absurdly long and basically clogs my log files. Is there a neat way to reduce the length of a JSON, purely for visually logging the data? (not in effect in production)

The basic approach is to reduce **arrays** over a length of 5 to [first 2, "...", last 2], and **dictionaries** with more than 4 items to {first 4, "..." : "..."}

The code below is ugly. I am aware that it should be a recursive solution that reduces the items in the same way for a JSON of arbitrary depth - it currently only does so for depth 2.

```
def log_reducer(response_log):
original_response_log = response_log
try:
    if type(response_log) == dict:
        if len(response_log) >= 4:  # {123456}
            response_log = dict(list(response_log.items())[:4])
            response_log.update({"...": "..."})  # {1234...}
        for key, value in response_log.items():
            if type(value) == list:
                if len(value) >= 5:  # {key:[123456]}
                    new_item = value[:2] + ['...'] + value[-2:]  # {[12...56]}
                    response_log.update({key: new_item})
            if type(value) == dict:
                if len(value) >= 4:  # {key:{123456}}
                    reduced_dict = dict(list(value.items())[:4])
                    reduced_dict.update({"...": "..."})
                    response_log.update({key: reduced_dict})  # {{1234...}}

    elif type(response_log) == list:
        if len(response_log) >= 5:  # [123456]
            response_log = response_log[:2] + ['...'] + response_log[-2:]  # [12...56]
        for inner_item in response_log:
            if type(inner_item) == list:
                if len(inner_item) >= 5:  # [[123456]]
                    reduced_list = inner_item[:2] + ['...'] + inner_item[-2:]  # [[12...56]]
                    response_log.remove(inner_item)
                    response_log.append(reduced_list)
            if type(inner_item) == dict:
                if len(inner_item) >= 4:  # [{123456}]
                    reduced_dict = dict(list(inner_item.items())[:4])
                    reduced_dict.update({"...": "..."})  # [{1234...}]
                    response_log.remove(inner_item)
                    response_log.append(reduced_dict)
except Exception as e:
    return original_response_log
return response_log
```

The returned response_log is then logged with logger.info(str(response_log))

As you can see, the fact that there can be either arrays or dictionaries at every level makes this task a little more complex, and I am struggling to find a library or code snipped of any kind which would simplify this. If anyone wants to give it a shot, I would appreciate it a lot.

you can use a test JSON like this to see it in effect:

```
test_json = {"works": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
             "not_affected": [{"1": "1", "2": "2", "3": "3", "4": "4", "5": "5"}],
             "1": "1", "2": "2", "3": "3",
             "removed": "removed"
             }
print("original", test_json)
reduced_log = log_reducer(test_json)
print("reduced", reduced_log)

print("original", test_json)
reduced_log = log_reducer([test_json])  # <- increases nesting depth
print("reduced", reduced_log)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer uses @calceamenta's idea, but implements the actual cutting-down logic:

```
def recursive_reduce(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, (float, str, int, bool, type(None))):
        return obj

    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        keys = list(sorted(obj))
        obj['...'] = '...'

        if len(keys) > 5:
            new_keys = keys[:2] + ["..."] + keys[-2:]
        else:
            new_keys = keys

        new_dict = {x:obj[x] for x in new_keys}
        for k, v in new_dict.items():
            new_dict[k] = recursive_reduce(v)

        return new_dict

    if isinstance(obj, list):
        if len(obj) > 5:
            new_list = obj[:2] + ["..."] + obj[-2:]
        else:
            new_list = obj

        for i, v in enumerate(new_list):
            new_list[i] = recursive_reduce(v)

        return new_list

    return str(obj)

test_json = {"works": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
             "not_affected": [{"1": "1", "2": "2", "3": "3", "4": "4", "5": "5"}],
             "1": "1", "2": "2", "3": "3",
             "removed": "removed"
             }

print("original", test_json)
reduced_log = recursive_reduce(test_json)
print("reduced", reduced_log)
```

Output:

```
original {'works': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'not_affected': [{'1': '1', '2': '2', '3': '3', '4': '4', '5': '5'}], '1': '1', '2': '2', '3': '3', 'removed': 'removed'}
reduced {'1': '1', '2': '2', '...': '...', 'removed': 'removed', 'works': [1, 2, '...', 5, 6]}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you both so much, this works exactly as intended

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite the **string representation** of dicts and lists in python using the **def __str__():** method. Using this just recursively call the print function on all elements. It can have a simple boilerplate like this:

```
def custom_print(obj):
    log_str = ''
    if type(obj) == list:
        for item in obj:
            log_str += custom_print(item)
    elif type(obj) == dict:
        for k, item in obj.items():
            custom_print(item)
```

Use this custom log function to print into your log file as per your log file format.

Comment: Sorry but I am unfamiliar with this, would the \_\_str__ function call the custom_print function or where would I put this? I'm getting `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str`